# Rcpp Makevars: portable -mpopcnt flag

Tags: c++, c++11, rcpp

I am using Rcpp and I am trying to make my `Makevars` file written to be portable. Initially this is my file:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -mpopcnt
PKG_CXX1XFLAGS = $(PKG_CXXFLAGS)
```

Then I modified it so I can make the C++11 flag portable:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -mpopcnt
PKG_CXX1XFLAGS = $(PKG_CXXFLAGS)
```

However, `-mpopcnt` is not a portable flag. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is somewhat sneaky trick you can play via `configure` --- which can be any executable top-level script.  Ie no fear of `autoconf` if you have it (and I should add that I quite like those tools).

So `configure` can just be a shell script, or even an R script executed via `#!/usr/bin/Rscript`, in which you test for the OS and/or compiler. If and only if the stars align you add `-mpopcnt`, else you don't.

And presto, you're compatible.

I blogged about that same idea once [in this post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/06/13#007_c++14_r_travis) which has this example to *remove* a C++14 switch:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Travis can let us run R 3.4.0 (from CRAN and the PPAs) but this R version
## does not know about C++14.  Even though we can select CXX_STD = C++14, R
## will fail as the version we use there was built in too old an environment,
## namely Ubuntu "trusty" 14.04.
##
## So we install g++-6 from another repo and rely on the fact that is
## defaults to C++14.  Sadly, we need R to not fail and hence, just on
## Travis, remove the C++14 instruction

if [[ "${CI}" == "true" ]]; then
    if [[ "${TRAVIS}" == "true" ]]; then 
        echo "** Overriding src/Makevars and removing C++14 on Travis only"
        sed -i 's|CXX_STD = CXX14||' src/Makevars
    fi
fi
```

You can use the exact same logic to *add* the switch you want to add.